# How can i Replace the text between brackets [ ] with response.data in jquery/js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

how can i change a string between the [] with response.data object my code like this:

```
var template = "<%= escape_javascript(eval(UserSetting.find_by_user_id_and_setting_name(User.current_user_id, 'own_user_grid_'+ grid_id).value)) %>"
```

template output looks like:

```
<body><p>DocType: [document_summarize_doctype]</p><b>Author ID: [document_author]</b></body>
```

i will change now in a each when i build the content the content between the `[document_summarize_doctype]` with this.document_summarize_doctype:

```
$j.each(response.data, function() {  $j('.own_content_overall').append('<div class="own_content">' + template + '<br><span style="border: 1px solid lightblue;"></div>');
          });
```

any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function, i found it some time ago on a SO, it's not mine but it does the job:

```
var substitute = function(str , sub )  {
    return str.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, function($0, $1) {
        return $1 in sub ? sub[$1] : $0;
    });
};

console.log(substitute('your are a [type_of_person]',{ type_of_person : 'good boiii'}))

// output : your are a good boiii
```

And your code will be like this: (if "item" keys exists in brackets, the string will be replaced)

```
$j.each(response.data, function(item) {
     $j('.own_content_overall').append(substitute('<div class="own_content">' + template + '<br><span style="border: 1px solid lightblue;"></div>', item));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `str` is `<body><p>DocType: [document_summarize_doctype]</p><b>Author ID: [document_author]</b></body>`:

```
str = str.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/, "[this.document_summarize_doctype]");
```

Comment: Hey Darren Thanks for ur answer but i have a problem, if u look at the code u see the other tag [document_author] so i need to change the complete content between the brackets with: this.str

Comment: Are you saying you need to replace the [document_author] bit too? Adding the g flag will do it for both: `str = str.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, "[this.document_summarize_doctype]");` If that's not what you're looking for, let me know.